# Alert if webpage has been updated

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, http-headers, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am creatin an app in Java that checks if a webpage has been updated.

However some webpages dont have a "last Modified" header.

I even tried checking for a change in content length but this method is not reliable as sometimes the content length changes without any modification in the webpage giving a false alarm.

I really need some help here as i am not able to think of a single foolproof method.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

If you connect the whole time to the webpage like this code it can help:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class main {

    String updatecheck = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        //Constantly trying to load page
        while (true) {

            try {
                System.out.println("Loading page...");

                // connecting to a website with Jsoup
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").userAgent("CHROME").get();

                // Selecting a part of this website with Jsoup
                String pick = doc.select("div.selection").get(0);

                // printing out when selected part is updated.
                if (updatecheck != pick){
                updatecheck = pick;
                System.out.println("Page is changed.");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Exception occured.... going to retry...  \n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[How to get notified after a webpage changes instead of refreshing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734065/how-to-get-notified-after-a-webpage-changes-instead-of-refreshing][1])

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most reliable option would be to store a hash of the page contet.

Comment: hashing is probably good... but my content length keeps changing by 2-3 characters... which might change the hashcode.... any idea why the content length changes by such small amounts???

Comment: I guess you could fine-tune the "diff check" by ignoring space characters or stuff like that before applying the hashing algorithm. Try something like `.trim()` first. I think there's no bullet-proof solution for this, you'll need to apply some heuristics.

Comment: @jedrus07: can you be a bit more explicit, please ?

Comment: If a page has an advert displayed with google ads- the hash will change. There are many other examples- in stack overflow you have time when comments were made- they change all the time untill they have the form: 'Sep 17 '11 at 10:08'. Before they have things like- '2 days ago'. There is a large number of not real changes on nearly any page that is not completely static.

Comment: Don't get me wrong- I would love your solution to work, but I am facing the same problem as the person in the question, and sadly hash does not work in 90% of the cases. But I guess there could be a website which you could monitor like that.

Comment: You're right. I must have misunderstood the question; I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that content-length changes then probably the webpages your are trying to check are dynamically generated and or not whatsoever a static in nature. If that is the case then even if you check the 'last-Modified' header it won't reflect the changes in content in most cases anyway.
I guess the only solution would be a page specific solution working only for a specific page, one page you could parse and look for content changes in some parts of this page, another page you could check by last modified header and some other pages you would have to check using the content length, in my opinion there is no way to do it in a unified mode for all pages on the internet. Another option would be to talk with people developing the pages you are checking for some markers which will help you determine if the page changed or not but that of course depends on your specific use case and what you are doing with it.